# Is there any way to install Sitecore 9 without Solr?

Tags: solr, azure, installation

We are planning to host the solution on Microsoft Azure PaaS, and using Azure Search instead of Solr. When we install Sitecore 9 on Azure PaaS, Solr is not required.

Is there any way to configure the developer box using Sitecore 9 without Solr?

Comment: In the below template https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/tree/master/Sitecore%209.0.1/XP Sitecore mentioned they will use Azure Search. Did you try this?

Comment: It this question more directed at running Sitecore 9 on a developer box with all Search providers disabled?

Answer (score 1):

It’s not too difficult as long as you can set up a search service for the purpose of local development.

**1.**  Setup Azure Search Service in the Azure Portal

**2.**  Add a new connection string called “Cloud.Search” – make sure to use the search URL and API key from your search service in the Azure portal when building the connection string e.g. `<add name="cloud.search" connectionString="serviceUrl=https://AzureSearchServiceURL;apiVersion=2015-02-28-preview;apiKey=AzureSearchServiceAPIKEY"/>`

**3.**  Change the app search definition in your web config under `<AppSettings>` to `<add key="search:define" value="Azure"/>`

**4.**  Rebuild your Sitecore Indexes

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is doable to install Sitecore 9 without Solr.
Sitecore will install successfully but it will not work without an Index Provider.
By configuring the Index Provider such as Azure Search post installation you will get Sitecore 9 up and running.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Lucene if you are running CMS-only mode (i.e. no Analytics/xDB). If you are running multi-server, multi-CD set up then best practice recommendation has been to use SOLR/Azure which you have already mentioned.

As far as Sitecore 9 installation documentation is concerned, here is the text.

> The Sitecore Experience Platform 9.0 rev. 171002 supports Solr,
>   Lucene, and Azure Search as search providers. If you want to use a
>   search index that works in both Analytics and ContentSearch, we
>   recommend that you use Solr.

Following is the Search Indexing Requirements.

[image]

I would suggest to review the installation documentation.

Comment: Lucene will not work on PaaS

Comment: My answer is related to development system where developer can program and not for production installation.

Comment: Right. But on this site we prefer answers to the questions actually asked :-)

Comment: @MarkCassidy Agree :)

Comment: To be fair to the answer, the question does state "developer box" not in production. However recommending lucene for SC9 project 9 times out of 10 is always going to get you down voted.